# regex in python/ansible

Tags: regex

I am new bee to regex, I have an example string : `account-device-v2-2-3-63-21900`

and using this regular expression `[1-9]-[0-9]-[0-9]*`

I am getting output as `1-2-3`
but my intention is to match/extract pattern `2-3-63`

Meaning to get digits with hyphens after v2 (or v1 etc), I don't need last digit part (21000 or any other number)

Any suggestions please?

Comment: You need to get only `2-3-63`? No need to use regex. If you need to get `1 digit except 0, dash, 1 digit, dash, 2 digit` then, just replace `*` with `{2}` like `[1-9]-[0-9]-[0-9]{2}`

Comment: @doctorgu I am not getting match, 
also, length of these digits can change. 
for e.g. lt could account-device-v2-2-3-102-21877

Comment: I answered. Please explain if you have more restriction.

Answer (score 0):

You want to get `1 or more digit except 0, dash, 1 or more digit, dash, 1 or more digit` from `account-device-v2-2-3-63-21900` or `account-device-v1-2-3-63-21900`?

Use `v[12]-([1-9]+?-[0-9]+?-[0-9]+?)-` and get first group.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/hMLGsK/1

Answer (score 0):

The pattern `[1-9]-[0-9]-[0-9]*` matches `2-2-3` because your pattern does not match the `v` and a digit part and this is the first part it can match.

Note that `[0-9]*` Matches optional digits, so `2-2-` could also be a match.

Using a capture group to get the value:

```
\bv[1-9][0-9]*-([1-9][0-9]*-[0-9]+-[0-9]+)
```

- `\bv[1-9][0-9]*-` Match `v1` or also possibly v20 etc..
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[1-9][0-9]*` Match a digit starting at 1
  - `-[0-9]+-[0-9]+` 2 parts matching `-` and 1 or more digits starting from 0
- `)` Close group 1

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SwCjoh/1)